# Converting object to another object

Tags: javascript, object, type-conversion

I've got an array of objects of this signature:

```
Note {
      _payload: [Object],
      blockText: 'ti',
      measure: [Measure],
      entries: [Array],
      start: 500,
      voiceId: undefined,
      octaveModifier: 0,
      previousNote: [Note],
      firstNoteOfPreviousBlock: [Chord],
      isTied: undefined,
      currentSubgroup: undefined,
      userInput: 'do refala misoti fa',
      crescendoIndex: undefined,
      chord: [Chord],
      _duration: 250
    }
```

There are getter functions baked into the API which allow me to access specific object properties, such as:
`block.elapsedTime` (which is the 'time' value), and `${note.alpha}${note.octave}`, which is the ('note' value).

Ultimately, I am trying to iterate through the list of objects so that I can return objects with time and note values in this format:

```
[
 {time: 0, note: 'C4', velocity: 0.7 },
 {time: 250, note: 'D4', velocity: 0.7}
 {time: 250, note: 'F4', velocity: 0.7}
 {time: 250, note: 'A4', velocity: 0.7}
 {time: 500, note: 'E4', velocity: 0.7}
 {time: 500, note: 'G4', velocity: 0.7}
 {time: 500, note: 'B4', velocity: 0.7}
 {time: 750, note: 'F4', velocity: 0.7}
]
```

I've tried to use map in this vein:
`` block.entries.map(note => [block.elapsedTime, `${note.alpha}${note.octave}`]) ``

but this returns arrays instead of objects.

Many thanks,
Nakul

Comment: Is `velocity` a constant value (0.7)? Will you get `note.alpha` from `previousNote' field? How is the structure of `block` object? Is it like `{block : elapsedTime, note:{alpha:1,octave:1}`?

Comment: If all the objects have the same `block.elapsedTime` value, why are they different in the output? There is no `alpha` and `octave` properties in `note`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath, the note class extends the block class. .alpha is an instance getter method that retrieves the data from lower down at the block level. It's payload is even richer than the one I printed.

Comment: @adiga, I meant to say that the payload listed above describes the signature of the object, not the array of objects. Each object in the object array has a different elapsed time value.

Comment: @NakulTiruviluamala so as `note` class extends `block` class, then note object will have `elapsedTime` property. so the returned object can be `{time: note.elapsedTime, note: '${}${}'}`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath thank you, I'll try this method too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array of elments returned from callback function. In your case it is an array:

```
[block.elapsedTime, `${note.alpha}${note.octave}`]
```

You should return an object instead of array like that:

```
block.entries.map((note) => ({
    time: block.elapsedTime,
    note: `${note.alpha}${note.octave}`
  })
);
```

You can add any required field inside the object.

Comment: But how would he get `block.elapsedTime`? It looks it's not being passed to the arrow function?

Comment: `block` variable is visible in the scope of `map` callback function

Comment: then `block.elapsedTime` will always constant for every iteration? I mean if `block.elapsedTime` is different for different `note` then the returned object will not capture that.

Comment: Yes. But in provider example it looks like a constant.

Comment: It works! Thanks again:   [
      { time: 0, note: 'C4' },
      { time: 0, note: 'C4' },
      { time: 250, note: 'D4' },
      { time: 250, note: 'F4' },
      { time: 250, note: 'A4' },
      { time: 500, note: 'E4' },
      { time: 500, note: 'G4' },
      { time: 500, note: 'B4' },
      { time: 750, note: 'F4' },
      { time: 750, note: 'F4' }
    ]